# Select total count and percent

Tags: postgresql

Say have table like:

```
user_uuid | value | state 
------------------+------+-------
uuid_1    |  111 | t
uuid_1    |  111 | f
uuid_1    |  111 | f
uuid_1    |  111 | f
uuid_2    |  333 | t
uuid_2    |  444 | t
uuid_2    |  555 | f
uuid_3    |  666 | t
uuid_4    |  777 | f
uuid_1    |  222 | t
uuid_1    |  222 | t
```

Task is select total count for each user_uuid and percent from total count to count with some value and state.
For example:
total count for uuid_1 is 6.

We need to get percent with value = 111 and status 'true'.

For 'uuid_1' count is 1. So need to calculate percent from 1 to 6

For 'uuid_2' and others counts are 0 so percents are 0 too.

I tryid this SQL:

```
 SELECT tq.user_uuid
     , COUNT(1) AS total
     , t.cnt
  FROM test_query tq
 CROSS
  JOIN (SELECT COUNT(user_uuid) AS cnt FROM test_query ) AS t
 GROUP
    BY tq.user_uuid, t.cnt;
```

But i cannot get how to select in JOIN part count for some conditions (like state=true, value=111)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `SUM(CASE...` for this purpose.

```
SELECT
    user_uuid,
    COUNT(*) cnt,
    ROUND (100.0 * (SUM(CASE WHEN value = '111' AND state = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) / COUNT(*), 1) AS percent
FROM
    t
GROUP BY
    user_uuid;
```

> ```
> user_uuid | cnt | percent
> :-------- | --: | ------:
> uuid_2    |   3 |     0.0
> uuid_3    |   1 |     0.0
> uuid_1    |   6 |    16.7
> uuid_4    |   1 |     0.0
> ```

As [a_horse_with_no_name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name) has pointed out, you can use `COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE...)` syntax too.

```
SELECT
    user_uuid,
    COUNT(*) cnt,
    ROUND (100.0 * (COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE value = '111' AND state = true)) / COUNT(*), 1) AS percent
FROM
    t
GROUP BY
    user_uuid;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=12cd76d307900c4e5b755c9972531bce)*

Comment: Alternatively: `count(*) filter (where ...)`

Comment: Is it possible use with JOIN?

Comment: Yes it is, but don't you think it is more clear in this way?